# Is this an improper SPI Bus format?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, spi, embedded

I have been attempting a modified star topology for my SPI bus. In my application I have my SPI bus split to several ports. These ports have 1 to 3 slave devices connected in series to each other. Is there anything wrong with this type of SPI format?

[image]

Also is it okay for the SPI bus to loop around a PCB like it is below?

I am asking this since my microcontroller is on a motherboard which talks to several daughterboards. Each of these daughterboards has one slave device. Some of the daughterboards are connected in series with other daughterboards.

[image]

Comment: If slow to moderate clock speeds are used then it shouldn't be a problem unless your circuit board is 3 metres x 3 metres. Detail required.

Comment: It's not terribly uncommon for the same type of chips to be connected in serial (as opposed to parallel) with an SPI interface.  Usually there's a select signal involved, and the chips just operate as FIFO latches until the 'select signal' is activated and the data is latched into the individual chips.  Perhaps that is why you observed serial (or "Daisy Chained") connections.  Doing this with individual boards is a bit unusual, but should work, within reason.  I happen to have a series of MAX4820's running in this fashion now.

Comment: @Andyaka The motherboard is about 4"x 3" with the daughter boards being about 2" x 2"